# How do I change options in a repeating section based on the number of items?

Tags: cognito-forms

I would like to add additional options to show only for additional repeating section items, but not the first one.

Comment: Can you provide more details about the types of options you are trying to add?  Is this additional fields you only want to show for the second repeating section?  Please describe what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: In second repeating section i need to put one more textbox but its not going to show in first repeating section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within [repeating sections](https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/repeating-sections), you can use the `ItemNumber` within calculations to determine the item number of a repeating section.

To conditionally show fields in repeating section items after the first, do the following:

1. Select `Show This Field` - `When` for the field you want to conditionally show
2. Select the `Advanced Editor` tab
3. Enter this calculation `=ItemNumber > 1`
4. Click `Save`

This will make the field inside the repeating section only appear when it is not the first repeating section item.